# connecting with Sqlexpress

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio, datasource

i am trying to connect the sql with a database on server. So when i entered the data source. its showing me Error **Unrecognized escape sequence**
Please help me out.

```
string constring = "Data Source=DVSQL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=user;Password=****";
```

i tried below both ways then its showing me Error **Unable to connect any of specified SQL host**

```
string constring = "Data Source=DVSQL\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=user;Password=****"; 

string constring = "Data Source=DVSQL/SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=user;Password=****";
```

What is the mistake i am doing when i check the connection using TEST BUTTON.. its showing me **TEST CONNECTION SUCCEEDED** . When i am calling from program its not connection. Why its like that. i am using VS 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing an @ sign before your first sql connection statement will prevent the string from including escape sequences.

```
string constring = @"Data Source=DVSQL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=user;Password=****";
```

Maybe something in the password is throwing it off.

Comment: do i need to give a `"` after the semicolun

Comment: I have made this tables and other things using MySQL community server 5.5.29 from my home and i took the software to my workpalce to check this out, wether this is working or not. But in my work place the data base is created in Visual studio management 2008R. and database is in .dbo format. But in my home i made it in Scheme the table name. So my is that the reason its not communicating

Comment: I updated the statement to remove the rogue quote.  ;)  In order to use your MySql database at work, you will need to convert it to Sql Server.  Here's a tool that should help you:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/02/07/mysql-to-sql-server-migration-how-to-use-ssma.aspx